# How can Community improve edit suggestions?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, community-bot

So, when looking as an edit review for a thing I posted I noticed this line:

> Community has approved 545 edit suggestions and rejected 123 edit suggestions and improved 1 edit suggestion

This is referring to the Community bot account that's used to help out in various automatic ways around the site.  While I'm a little surprised that it rejects edits, I'm even more surprised that it edits and then approves them.  How can it do this and what is that 'improved edit suggestion' that it has?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Community gets the credit when the OP does stuff with an edit suggestion.

Comment: And that's only happened once ever? -_-

Comment: I could be wrong, but did you approve [this recent edit](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34324) to your answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That did strike me as odd, so I went digging in Community's review history, and [found the answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/92073/revisions). Obvious in retrospect, but I had to see it to understand it.

**This can be caused by a user being deleted**, because all database activity of a deleted user is reassigned to Community.

1. User A writes a post.
2. Another user makes an edit suggestion.
3. [User A approves and edits the suggestion, creating an improvement event.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/92073/revisions)
4. Time passes and User A is deleted.
5. Community inherits all post activity from the deleted User A, including the improvement event.

I'm surprised that's only happened once so far.

Community. Always there to catch things we drop.

Comment: I am also super surprised that's only happened once in the history of our site ! D:  Pretty cool, though.  I guess if you don't want your account deleted, improving and accepting an edit is the way to go XD

Comment: Fascinating! Marvelous sleuthing.